# Z dimension insanely skewed?

Tags: dimensions

My model shows dimensions of 1.35, 3.9, and 100000000000000000.000000. It looks perfectly fine in my viewport though. The z size is very similar to the other dimensions. I have applied all transformations in object mode. I am clueless what else to do. It is causing me to be unable to import into unreal. Any suggestion how to fix?[image]

Answer (score 3):

welp, apparently I had a stray vertice a million miles in the sky. I was able to pinpoint it and delete it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how  you located the stray?